# Как форматировать текст в комментариях к ответу?

Tags: форматирование, обсуждение

Как сделать список в комментарии к ответу?
Например:

1. Строка 1
2. Строка 2
3. Строка 3

У меня всё пишет в одну строчку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предполагают переносов строк, списков и, вообще, рзавернутой дискуссии.

Answer (score 6):

Комментарии не предназначены для представления значимой информации на этом сайте. Они - всего лишь средство для вопросов, замечаний и уточнений. Поэтому в комментариях нельзя сделать:

- Списки
- Код (только в строку)
- Блоки цитирования

Если вы хотите дополнить свой вопрос подробностями - размещайте их прямо в ответе. Неожиданно, но именно для этого вопрос и предназначен. Так их увидят все читатели, а не только собеседник, которому вы адресовали комментарий.

---

Кстати:

> Вам не сложно будет привести наиболее оптимальное решение для моих задач на примере моего проекта?

Такие запросы - вне рамок допустимых на Stack Overflow. Если ваш вопрос требует от человека написания нескольких страниц текста или кода, а также пары часов работы, адресуйте этот вопрос на фриланс-биржу.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь вы найдете все, что вам нужно:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Так всё таки в комментариях можно делать списки? По вашей ссылке описана графа "Простые списки". Только не пойму как ей пользоваться

Comment: @koverflow _Комментарии поддерживают только курсив, полужирный шрифт, код и несколько сокращений для ссылок._